# "Object.Object.string" property validation not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

I have a problem with my Custom ValidationRule.

Here is my .cs file:

```cs
public class LengthValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }
    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int length = value.ToString().Length;

        if ((length < Min) || (length > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              Resources.Strings.ProperFieldLength + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it in two cases in .xaml file

First(Working):

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox"  
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         IsEnabled="{Binding InEdit, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedUser.Login" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                 ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validation:LengthValidationRule Min="8" Max="20"/>
                <Validation:RegexValidationRule RegEx="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And Second(Not Working - not even firing validator):

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="nameTextBox"  
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         IsEnabled="{Binding InEdit, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedUser.Acceptor.Name" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                 ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validation:LengthValidationRule Min="1" Max="10"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I found it out, that the reason of this error is this "nested" Binding:

```
Binding Path="SelectedUser.Acceptor.Name"
```

But I have no idea how make it to work.

Comment: Do you fire `PropertyChanged` event for the `Name` property in your view-model?

Comment: No, I only RaisePropertyChanged for SelectedUser, because I'm using EF model class for that fields. I don't know how to raise it for each field of User class

Comment: Ok I see that I have to made property for each of User's inner properities with RaiseProperyChanged in setter.